# How to keep a gamepad bluetooth device always on?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, joystick

I have this bluetooth gamepad (it is used with VR, as remote camera-shot, as joystick, etc):

[image]

This device turns off in 5 minutes if I don't touch it. Well, I don't want it to do that, I want to keep it on for one hour, for example. I tried to use `bluetoothctl connect 13:57:90:05:0E:31` every 30 seconds, but it doesn't work: it turns off in 5 minutes. I don't tried to `disconnect` and `connect` it because it could delay doing that operation and it may not connect and I will have to turn it off and on physically. I need it to be **always on and ready to use**.

Is there any way to send "something" to this device to keep it on for the time I need?

My system: Debian 10 x64, TP-Link UB400 USB Bluetooth dongle and the device info is:

```
[bluetooth]# info 13:57:90:05:0E:31 
Device 13:57:90:05:0E:31 (public)
    Name: Gamepad.
    Alias: Gamepad.
    Class: 0x00000540
    Icon: input-keyboard
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Human Interface Device... (00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v05ACp3232d0001
```

Using Python evdev, this device capabilities are:

```
gamepad.capabilities()
{0: [0, 1, 3, 4], 1: [304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319], 3: [(0, AbsInfo(value=0, min=-127, max=127, fuzz=0, flat=15, resolution=0)), (1, AbsInfo(value=0, min=-127, max=127, fuzz=0, flat=15, resolution=0)), (2, AbsInfo(value=0, min=-127, max=127, fuzz=0, flat=15, resolution=0)), (5, AbsInfo(value=0, min=-127, max=127, fuzz=0, flat=15, resolution=0)), (16, AbsInfo(value=0, min=-1, max=1, fuzz=0, flat=0, resolution=0)), (17, AbsInfo(value=0, min=-1, max=1, fuzz=0, flat=0, resolution=0))], 4: [4]}

gamepad.capabilities(verbose=True)
{('EV_SYN', 0): [('SYN_REPORT', 0), ('SYN_CONFIG', 1), ('SYN_DROPPED', 3), ('?', 4)], ('EV_KEY', 1): [(['BTN_A', 'BTN_GAMEPAD', 'BTN_SOUTH'], 304), (['BTN_B', 'BTN_EAST'], 305), ('BTN_C', 306), (['BTN_NORTH', 'BTN_X'], 307), (['BTN_WEST', 'BTN_Y'], 308), ('BTN_Z', 309), ('BTN_TL', 310), ('BTN_TR', 311), ('BTN_TL2', 312), ('BTN_TR2', 313), ('BTN_SELECT', 314), ('BTN_START', 315), ('BTN_MODE', 316), ('BTN_THUMBL', 317), ('BTN_THUMBR', 318), ('?', 319)], ('EV_ABS', 3): [(('ABS_X', 0), AbsInfo(value=0, min=-127, max=127, fuzz=0, flat=15, resolution=0)), (('ABS_Y', 1), AbsInfo(value=0, min=-127, max=127, fuzz=0, flat=15, resolution=0)), (('ABS_Z', 2), AbsInfo(value=0, min=-127, max=127, fuzz=0, flat=15, resolution=0)), (('ABS_RZ', 5), AbsInfo(value=0, min=-127, max=127, fuzz=0, flat=15, resolution=0)), (('ABS_HAT0X', 16), AbsInfo(value=0, min=-1, max=1, fuzz=0, flat=0, resolution=0)), (('ABS_HAT0Y', 17), AbsInfo(value=0, min=-1, max=1, fuzz=0, flat=0, resolution=0))], ('EV_MSC', 4): [('MSC_SCAN', 4)]}

gamepad.leds()
[] # it has no leds to receive on/off data
```

Comment: What model is the device?

Comment: @harrymc here, the importer calls it VRM300, but it is called only here, in Argentina.

Comment: Can it be connected via USB?

Comment: No. It only charges battery when connected.

Comment: Does it also enter sleep when connected for charging?

Comment: No. Not even it stays always on... you can't turn it off. You do it and it powers on automatically.

Comment: So connecting it for charging is one way of avoiding sleep?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128045/discussion-between-mario-mey-and-harrymc).